# Declare attribute selectors in SCSS?

Tags: sass

In CSS I have this attribute selectors

```
[class*="className_option1"] {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

I'm new to SCSS, and would like to know that what is the best way to do it in SCSS?

Comment: you want to repeat that for multiple options ?

Comment: no not really just once

Comment: So why do you need SCSS ?